# How can i transform an Array JSON in a Object JSON in c++?

Tags: c++, json

I'm trying to transform a JSON Array in a JSON Object in c++.

Basically right now i'm doing something like that

```
outputFile["something"].push_back(parsedFile["something"]);
```

And it's giving me a json like

```
{
    "something": [
        {
     ....
        }
     ]
}
```

but i want

```
{
    "something": {
     ....
     }
}
```

Do anyone have a idea to transform my "something" to a object ?

I already tried to do something like that, but it's not working

```
auto result = nlohmann::json::object();
result["item_name"] = parsedFile["something"];
outputFile["something"].push_back(result);
```

Comment: `outputFile["something"] = parsedFile["something"];`?

Comment: @Jarod42 oh damn, yeah it's working :') my mistake, thanks